# in elasticsearch how to write Aggregations terms in order to group by time per 5 minutes

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

some data in elasticsearch like this:

```
{"info":"fwefwefwef","is_fail":0,"result":404,"key":"845722d85520c91f345b08aba3233c96","duration":1,"lts_at":1479786902}
```

'lts_at is' timestamp, and i want to group by datas in 'floor(lts_at/300)'

```
{ 
"aggs": {
    "per_5minute": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "lst_at/300"
        }
    }
}
```

how to write the Aggregations query?

Comment: What's the result you're getting from the aggs you've mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a [`date_histogram` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) with interval 5 minutes instead, like this:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "per_5minute" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "lst_at",
                "interval" : "5m"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to stick with the `terms` aggregation, then you need to use a script instead:

```
{ 
"aggs": {
    "per_5minute": {
        "terms": {
            "script": {
                "inline": "Math.floor(doc.lst_at.value / 300)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For this to work, you need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/modules-scripting-security.html#enable-dynamic-scripting)